# How to train a LogisticRegression classifier to read from a second dataset?

Tags: python, classification

I am trying to use scikit-learn to train a LogisticRegression classifier:

1. My training data has 2 columns: “text”, “category”.
2. I have a second dataset with 2 columns also: “text”, “category”.

This is what I want to accomplish:

While training the classifier, each time a “text” record from my training data is identical to a record in the second dataset, I want the classifier to assign the second dataset’s “category” to it.

Comment: Create a third data set and use it for training the classifier. This third data set will have the training data of the first data set, but with the updated labels from the second data set.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but not all the records in the training data set have a match in the second data set. The second data se is just few records that have official labels. So I just want to account for these direct matches in my training.

Comment: I know. I'm just telling you to do some data processing/cleaning before training the classifier; that means, you can manually create a third data set with the data you want to use and then simply input that third data set to the classifier for the training.